# How to not leave input field after tab key pressed? (javascript/html)

Tags: javascript, html, input

I wondered if I could have an input field, that, if someone (who is typing in the input field) presses the TAB key, not switches focus (so it must stay focused on the first input field and not go to the next).

Also, it must detect when someone presses the TAB key, and execute a function when the TAB key is *released*.
The code has to be in **pure javascript**.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Simple version: `<input onkeydown="return (event.keyCode||event.which) != 9;">`  flexible version: create function and call it on key down/up

Comment: @num8er that will work just fine, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `onkeydown` to declare a function on the `document` to capture all key presses (or just use the specific element). Use this to check for tab and execute your function accordingly.

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 9) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert("Tab");
    }
};
```

Use `preventDefault()` to prevent the default action for the key pressed.